# Приоритет выборки WHERE ... OR

Tags: mysql

**Задача**: в выборке один ко многим вернуть только одну запись в порядке приоритета.

Есть 2 таблицы: таблица с товарами `Goods` и таблица с ценами `Price`. Одной товарной позиции может быть задано несколько цен с параметрами `val1`, `val2`. Значения параметров `1` или `0`.

```
SELECT g.name, p.price
FROM Goods g, Price p
WHERE g.id=1
      AND g.id=p.g_id
      AND ((p.val1=0 AND p.val2=0)
            OR (p.val1=1 AND p.val2=0)
            OR (p.val1=0 AND p.val2=1)
            OR (p.val1=1 AND p.val2=1))
```

Данный запрос вернет все записи из таблицы `Price`. Задача вернуть только одну в порядке приоритета. Приоритет следующий:

1. `val1 = 1 AND val2 = 1` (есть все параметры)
2. `val1 = 1 AND val2 = 0` (только первый)
3. `val1 = 0 AND val2 = 1` (только второй)
4. `val1 = 0 AND val2 = 0` (нет ни одного)

Возможно ли это?

Comment: Возможно. Только нужно вычислить приоритет, отсортировать по-приоритету, и ещёраз выбрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я упростил ваши OR. А сортировка идет по простому арифметическому выражению. Если обе 1, она дает 3, если первая то 2, если вторая 1, иначе 0. При сортировке в обратном порядке получаем первой как раз нужную запись. Применяем `limit` остается только она.

```
SELECT g.name, p.price
  FROM Goods g, Price p
 WHERE g.id=1 AND g.id=p.g_id
   AND p.val1 in(0,1) AND p.val2 in(0,1)
 ORDER BY p.val1*2+p.val2 desc
 LIMIT 1
```

Если разыскиваемые значения не 0 и 1 то подобрать подходящее арифметическое выражение, если не получается - преобразовать параметры к подходящим числам примерно так `if(val=10,1,0)`

Comment: Спасибо! Натолкнули на простое решение )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT first 1 g.name, p.price,  
     case when p.val1=1 then 
     case when p.val2=1 then 1 else 2 end 
else case when p.val2=1 then 3 else 4 end end  priority1 
FROM Goods g, Price p    WHERE g.id=1 AND g.id=p.g_id AND ((p.val1=0 AND p.val2=0) OR (p.val1=1 AND p.val2=0) 
OR (p.val1=0 AND p.val2=1) OR (p.val1=1 AND p.val2=1)) 
order by 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.name, p.price 
FROM Goods g, Price p 
WHERE g.id=1 AND g.id=p.g_id 
AND ((p.val1=0 AND p.val2=0) OR (p.val1=1 AND p.val2=0) OR (p.val1=0 AND p.val2=1) OR (p.val1=1 AND p.val2=1))  

order by  case when p.val1=1 AND p.val2=1 then 1
               when p.val1=1 AND p.val2=0 then 2
               when p.val1=0 AND p.val2=1 then 3
               when p.val1=0 AND p.val2=0 then 4 end asc limit 1
```

Добавь order by с case и  limit 1 чтобы вернуть одну строку. Можно даже в where условие не указывать, достаточно order by