# MySQL приоритет выборки по столбцам

Tags: mysql, select

Внимательно изучил вот эту тему [Приоритет выборки WHERE ... OR](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528870/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-where-or), но у меня другой вопрос.

Здесь создал тест, но что-то барахлит ресурс: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa25a8/5

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id INT, head VARCHAR(90), main_tag VARCHAR(90), tags VARCHAR(90), texts TEXT);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1,'bowling balls','balls', 'four;Chuck', 'Chuck Norris once ate four 30lb bowling balls without chewing.'),
                                    (2,'rilled bird','bird', 'kill;stone', 'Chuck Norris killed two stones with one bird.'),
                                    (4,'The quickest way','Chuck', 'quick;Chuck', 'The quickest way to a man\'s heart is with Chuck Norris\' fist.'),
                                    (5,'Lady GaGa','IE', 'canvas;explorer', 'Lady GaGa uses canvas in IE.'),
                                    (6,'Wild program','program', 'form;WEB', 'Chuck Norris programs do not accept input.'),
                                    (7,'Chuck vs Rambo','Rambo', 'cool;Chuck', 'To Silvester Stallone, everything contains a vulnerability.');
```

В общем, мне нужна сортировка при выводе **по приоритету**: сначала, если слово 'Chuck' **встречается в 'head', затем в 'main_tag' и т.д.**

В голову пришло только:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE head LIKE '%Chuck%' OR main_tag LIKE '%Chuck%'
OR tags LIKE '%Chuck%' OR texts LIKE '%Chuck%'
```

И ORDER BY здесь, понятное дело, ни при чем.

UPD: **See solution** - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ad2235/12

Comment: Может, для каждого поля свой SELECT прописать и объединить их UNION ALL?

Comment: Вот тут https://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%81-where.7706/ человеку голову морочили, но так и не ответили.

Comment: Вот так, что ли: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa25a8/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приоритеты операторов проявляются при проверке строки, а порядок в котором строки выдаются запросом называются "порядок сортировки", а не "приоритет" и задаются соответственно предложением order by. Учитывая, что в MySQL любое логическое выражение возвращает 0 или 1 то нам надо отсортировать выборку так, что бы срабатывание условия, давшее 1 оказалось первым, т.е. сортируем по условию в обратном (desc) порядке:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE head LIKE '%Chuck%' OR main_tag LIKE '%Chuck%'
    OR tags LIKE '%Chuck%' OR texts LIKE '%Chuck%'
 ORDER BY head LIKE '%Chuck%' OR main_tag LIKE '%Chuck%' desc,
          tags LIKE '%Chuck%' OR texts LIKE '%Chuck%' desc
```

В принципе последнее условие можно было не добавлять, потому что первое уже выведет на первое место совпадения в head.

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa25a8/8)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ad2235/3 - только не смейтесь

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa25a8/8 да, но здесь Chuck в head НЕ НА ПЕРВОМ месте.

Comment: @ChooHwan Ну если ALL добавить к UNION, оно в принципе будет рабочим, но это не оговорено стандартами и БД _имеет право_ вернуть записи не в том порядке, как были заданы UNION ALL (хотя этого и не делает, потому что обходить их подряд самый простой путь выполнения :) )

Comment: @ChooHwan Не надо ставить OR в ORDER BY, он же превращает два логических условия в одно и по нему идет сортировка. Используйте запятую и не забывайте поставить desc у каждого условия http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa25a8/9

Comment: @ChooHwan А еще все выражения для ORDER BY можно проверять в самом select, что бы видеть значения, которые они возвращают и понимать что как происходит: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa25a8/11

Comment: Спасибо!!! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ad2235/11

Comment: А скажите, FULL TEXT слишком замедляет выборку?

Comment: @ChooHwan Если вы про full text serach то он строит свои, полнотекстовые индексы и работает по ним. по идее он должен быть гораздо быстрее чем like '%x%', который заведомо перебирает всю таблицу. Но сталкиваться с ним не приходилось, так что не могу сказать какие там подводные грабли могут найтись

Comment: Таблица имеет уже 21000 рядов. MATCH AGAINST будут возвращать сортировку такую же, как LIKE?

Comment: И еще вопрос. Перечисления в MATCH(head, main_tag, tags) задают проиритет выборки?

Comment: @ChooHwan Вряд ли. На порядок записей влияет только ORDER BY, так что он должен быть указан. и в нем надо указать что то, что дает требуемое число. А что возвращает MATCH или специальные функции приоритетов посмотрите сами, задав эти функции в самом списке select, как я показывал в примерах

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f57355a/2 - облом. Я понял, почему.

Comment: Хотя http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html "возвращенные строки столбцов автоматически сортируются, начиная с наиболее релевантных."